# Get Last Change Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
StockCode   TimeStamp          UnitPrice    TrnDate
---------------------------------------------------------------
360120      0x000000000DBE9EED  16.8000 2015-02-13 0:00:00.000
360120      0x000000000DBEE175  16.8000 2015-02-17 00:00:00.000
360120      0x000000000DC177AC  16.8000 2015-02-24 00:00:00.000
360120      0x000000000DC1EEFB  16.0000 2015-02-25 00:00:00.000
360120      0x000000000DC1E9BE  16.8000 2015-02-25 00:00:00.000
360120      0x000000000DC261CE  16.0000 2015-02-27 00:00:00.000
360120      0x000000000DC2628D  16.8000 2015-02-27 00:00:00.000 **
360120      0x000000000DFC46EA  16.8000 2015-03-02 00:00:00.000
```

The query needs to return 2015-02-27 where price went form 16.000 to 16.8000,
which is the last price change date for this item in the price history table.
The way I wrote it, the query it only works if the price didn't change back to a price that exists in the table for that stock code.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(MinTrnDate) as LastTrnDate
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         a.UnitPrice, MIN(TrnDate) as MinTrnDate 
     FROM 
         (SELECT   
             ph.StockCode,
             CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4), (ph.InvoiceValue/ ph.InvoiceQty)) as  UnitPrice,
             ph.TrnDate
          FROM 
             ArSalesMove ph 
          JOIN 
             ArCustomer c WITH(NOLOCK) on ph.Customer = c.Customer  
          WHERE   
             LTRIM(RTRIM(ph.StockCode)) = '360120'
             AND (ph.InvoiceValue/ ph.InvoiceQty) > 0
             AND c.PriceCode = 'A') AS a
     WHERE 
         a.UnitPrice > 0
     GROUP BY a.UnitPrice) AS b
HAVING 
     MIN(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), UnitPrice)) <> MAX(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), UnitPrice)) --Used to exclude stockcodes with no change...
```

Comment: I suspect this is something that could be easily solved using windowing functions, but they aren't supported on all RDBMSs. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is in a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Comment: which is the last price change date for this item in the price history table.

Looking at your sample data set both rows for StockCode=360120 have TrnDate= '2015-02-27 00:00:00.000', so how would SQL determine which one is 'last'?

For example, maybe the price went from 16.80 down to 16.00. If the dates are exactly the same, there's no way to tell if the price was increased or decreased.

Comment: There is a Timestamp field, does that help?see the amended data above.

Comment: No, a Timestamp field doesn't really help. It's only real use is to tell if a row *changed* underneath you (concurrency detection)... whether it's *different*.

Comment: @Arraylist try selecting maximum timestamp and maximum date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012 or newer:

```
;WITH
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT  *,
                LAG(UnitPrice, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode ORDER BY TrnDate) AS LastPrice
        FROM    PriceHistory
    )

SELECT      StockCode, MAX(TrnDate)
FROM        cte
WHERE       UnitPrice != LastPrice
GROUP BY    StockCode
```

For SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
;WITH
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode ORDER BY TrnDate) AS RowNumber
        FROM    PriceHistory
    )

SELECT      c2.StockCode, MAX(c2.TrnDate)
FROM        cte c1
INNER JOIN  cte c2 ON c1.StockCode = c2.StockCode AND c1.RowNumber + 1 = c2.RowNumber
WHERE       c1.UnitPrice != c2.UnitPrice
GROUP BY    c2.StockCode
```